# Using the Address property for external references in a non continuous multi selection

Tags: vba

I have an InputBox that returns a range:

`Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select Cells", Type:=8)`

Where I want the user to make a multi-selection. I am putting a summation of the cell reference in a different sheet as a string in some_cell via:

`some_cell.Value = "=SUM(" & rng.Address(Exteral:=True) & ")"`

This works fine for a continuous reference (eg 'Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$100) but when I have a separated multi selection, the external reference is not applied to any cell references past the first one (eg 'Sheet1'!$A$1,$A$2)

I solved this with a Replace function:

`some_cell.Value = Replace("=SUM(" & rng.Address(Exteral:=True) & ")", ",", "'Sheet1'!")`

But that seems like a silly solution.
Am I using the Address property wrong? Why wouldn't it apply the external reference to every separated cell reference?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function to handle this:

```vb
Sub tester()
    
    Dim addr, arr, rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select Cells", Type:=8)
    
    Debug.Print ExternalAddress(rng)
    
End Sub

Function ExternalAddress(rng As Range)
    Dim addr, arr, pre
    addr = rng.Address(external:=True)
    If rng.Areas.Count > 1 Then
        arr = Split(addr, "!")
        pre = arr(0) & "!"
        addr = pre & Replace(arr(1), ",", "," & pre)
    End If
    ExternalAddress = addr
End Function
```